# Display questions with badges it has earned for the asker

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Feature request:

Is it possible to display the list of badges a question has earned for the person who has asked it?

Explanation:

I ask a question 'xyz' and I earned `Notable Question` and `Good question` badges for it. Display the badges along with the question.

Comment: Does everyone have to see this noise? Or only the user who posted?

Comment: The problem I see with it is that they won't add any new information to the post. Notable Question means it had 1000 visits - already displayed. Favourite Question - number of favourites is already displayed. Notable Question - votes are displayed. Bounty information is displayed as well. The only one which is not obvious is Tumbleweed...

Comment: A question can earn many badges for the person asking question, so display all those badges.

Comment: @KirkHammett What's the purpose of it? Does everyone need to see it? Anyone can go to your badges and find out which questions they were awarded for. But why would you want to have it on the question itself?

Comment: Not saying I like it - but it would look something like this.. http://i.stack.imgur.com/OGloa.png

Comment: Badges are just decoration! There's no benefit for them to be on the question page. Instead, you could possibly propose that they appear next to the questions, and similarly answers, on the users profile page.

Comment: Why down votes?

Comment: @KirkHammett In this instance, downvotes on meta just mean that they wouldn't want this feature implemented.

Comment: @KirkHammett - on meta, downvotes signify a "nay" vote in a show of hands. ;)

Comment: @KirkHammett - Meta works a bit differently. Downvote here means, they don't agree with your proposal. Not necessary that your question is bad.

Comment: Ok, I understand.

Comment: Downvotes also suggest lack of reason why this would be a good idea

Answer (score 6):

The primary purpose of the Stack Exchange sites is to collect knowledge in a Q&A style. Badges are used on the site to entice users into performing tasks that are mostly beneficial to the system as a whole.

The result of these tasks is what benefits the network<strike>, while all the badges really are, is noise</strike>!

Therefore I don't see that the majority of the community will ever want this feature implemented. Having said that, and as I have mentioned in a comment above, you could always propose that this list of badges be displayed next to the corresponding question and/or answer on the actual users profile page.

Bear in mind though that even the latter suggestion is bound to get shot down solely because of the server overhead and processing this swanky new pile of <strike>noises</strike> badges will contribute!